# Using preg_match to filter youtube URLS in php

Tags: php, youtube, preg-match

I am using the following code to convert youtube URLS in my posts to embedded videos. But this is not working if I add the URL with https:// and youtu.be format. How should I fix it?

```
  $youtube_url = "/http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?(.*?)v=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(\S*)/i";
  if (preg_match($youtube_url, $text, $youtube)){
   // echo "match found";
  }
```

Comment: `"/https?:\/\/(?:www)?\.youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/watch(?:\?(.*?)&|\?)v=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(\S*)/i";`?

Comment: @GlitchMr, how about posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Regexp would look like `/https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/watch(?:\?(.*?)&|\?)v=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(\S*)/i`

`s?` means optional s character. There is not really much else to comment in this regexp.